# Why is the Navigation Bar on top of the UIViewWeb? (Beginner in OBJ-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, theos

I have a small problem. 
Basically, I have a `UIWebView` that is located under the navigation bar, so I need to scroll down to view the contents, and it scrolls up at the end. How Do I make the `UIWebView` appear right below the navigation bar?

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    NSString *url=@"http://localhost/";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
    UINavigationItem*navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"iPaint"] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem*leftButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonPressed)] autorelease];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
UIBarButtonItem*rightButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonPressed)] autorelease];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}

-(void)leftButtonPressed{
//Code Here
}

-(void)rightButtonPressed{
//Code Here
}
@end
```

main.mm Code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        int ret = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"comvlad1kwebApplication", @"comvlad1kwebApplication");
        [p drain];
        return ret;
}

// vim:ft=objc
```

I am using Theos, so I don't have an Xcode, therefore I need to manually do it.
Thank you.

EDIT: Here is a link to a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72sPI.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are creating a `UINavigationBar` manually. What you want is to be using a `UINavigationController`, which is a view controller that manages a stack of other view controllers and navigation between them. In your application delegate, you probably have code that looks something like this:

```
// Assuming that your UIApplication Delegate has a _viewController ivar which is properly memory-managed.
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [_window addSubview:_viewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

That snippet of code creates an instance of `RootViewController` and sets it to be the main view controller in the application. What you want instead is to put a `RootViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`, like this:

```
// Assuming that your UIApplication Delegate has a _viewController ivar which is properly memory-managed.
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController] autorelease];
    [_window addSubview:navController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Once you've created a `UINavigationController` subclass, you should remove the `UINavigationBar` from your `RootViewController`, as it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set frame of views, based on controller's view's frame in viewDidLoad method. Set frame of webView and NavigationBar on viewWillAppear.

Also, probably you would want to use UINAvigationController, instead of adding UINavigationBar manually

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGrectZero];
    NSString *url=@"http://localhost/";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

```
    UINavigationItem*navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"iPaint"] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem*leftButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonPressed)] autorelease];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
UIBarButtonItem*rightButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonPressed)] autorelease];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];



}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
  CGRect r = self.view.bounds;
  r.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(navBar.frame);
  r.size.width = r.size.width - CGRectGetMaxY(navBar.frame);
  [webView setFrame:r];
}


-(void)leftButtonPressed{
//Code Here
}

-(void)rightButtonPressed{
//Code Here
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you please edit my code and fix it? I just started using ObjC and I am not very comfortable with it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have AppDelegate, I only have RootViewController.h, RootViewController.mm, and main.mm.?

Comment: Could you post your main.mm code then? You should inject this code wherever instance of RootViewControoler is initializing

Comment: I just included the main.mm in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Something is missed. There should be a code, that create RootViewContrller instance. Not sure about it. anyway, I've edited my code to create navigation bar manually, like you did.